# Assigning structs including pointers

Tags: c++, pointers, struct

Consider the following simple program. It just defines two variables `A` and `B` from `MyStruct` and then initializes `A`.

**How can I copy `A` to `B` with new pointers for `B`?**

If I use assignment operator, `firstMember` of `B` will be assigned with `firstMember` of `A` and whenever I change the value of `B.firstMember[i]`, the value of `A.firstMember[i]` will change. I already know that it can be done with a function, but is there any simpler way? Assuming that `MyStruct` can have lots pointers, writing a function doesn't seem to be good.

```
typedef struct MyStruct
{
    int * firstMember;
    int secondMember;
} MyStruct;

int main()
{
    MyStruct A;
    MyStruct B;

    Initialize(A);            // initializes A such that A.firstMember[0] != 5
    B = A;
    B.firstMember[0] = 5;
    cout<<A.firstMember[0];   // prints 5

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Use a copy constructor/overloaded assignment operator

Comment: Overload the assignment operator (`operator=`)with the desired behavior. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4421706/operator-overloading

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4172722/what-is-the-rule-of-three

Comment: @Mowji Or, you could just not use pointers and switch to things like `std::vector`

Comment: @Mowji let's be very clear that the best solution is to only use member variables which do not require any custom copying/deletion code  . Anything you can do with `int *firstMember`, you can almost certainly rewrite to use a well-behaved member.  As well as keeping your code simple and clear, this technique helps your compiler make efficient output.

Comment: @MattMcNabb Can you suggest any alternatives beside vectors? Thanks.

Comment: no, use `vector`. You could roll your own half-assed vector but that would be a waste of time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This falls into the ["Rule of 3"](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rule_of_three_%28C%2B%2B_programming%29).  Once you start managing raw pointers inside a class, you probably want to define a custom contructor, destructor, and assignment operator for this very reason.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, I don't understand why among two members, one is a pointer, and other is not. I am presuming that the first member which is a pointer points to a single integer. Here's an improved code snippet for the structure:

```
struct MyStruct
{
    int * firstMember;
    int secondMember;
    MyStruct& operator = (const MyStruct& src) {
      *firstMember = *src.firstMember;
      return *this;
    }
    MyStruct(int a = 0) {
      firstMember = new int(a);
      secondMember = a;
    }
    MyStruct(const MyStruct& src) {
        // deep copy
        firstMember = new int(*src.firstMember);
        secondMember = src.secondMember;
    }
    ~MyStruct() {
        if (firstMember)
          delete firstMember;
    }
};
```

Note, struct is a class with all members declared as public by default. Rather than having Initialize in C-way, better to use C++ proper construct like constructor, and you need to have copy constructor and assignment operator too.

Comment: Thank you very much. I didn't know how to 'deep copy'. Actually I didn't figure out what the name might be.

Comment: In deep copy you own the data, so, allocate per object, and assign whatever, in shallow copy, you copy the pointer, don't allocate, so, share teh pointer among several objects.

Comment: @Mowji do you accept the answer for my two cents :-)

Comment: I used your 'deep copy' in overloaded operator. But it seems that it doesn't work properly. Can you show me how to do this plz?

Comment: In this solution you also need a destructor.